# Adding new key to all keys in python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, key, tuples

I currently have this dict:

```
initial_dict = {'val_1': 2, 'val_2': 4}
```

And I`m looking for the more efficient way to add a new 'foo' key to all keys to get:

```
final_dict = {('foo' ,'val_1'): 2, ('foo' ,'val_2'): 4}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want [`dict comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

```
>>> { ('foo', key): val for key, val in initial_dict.items()}
{('foo', 'val_1'): 2, ('foo', 'val_2'): 4}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really wanted to, you could re-build the dictionary using a comprehension:

```
new_dict = {('foo', k) : v for k, v in initial_dict.items()}
```

```
print(new_dict)
{('foo', 'val_1'): 2, ('foo', 'val_2'): 4}
```

To index, you would now use `new_dict[('foo', 'val_1')]`.

However, it appears you're trying to build a multi-indexed dictionary. Why not make it a nested dict instead?

```
new_dict = {'foo' : initial_dict}
```

```
print(new_dict)
{'foo': {'val_1': 2, 'val_2': 4}}
```

Now, you'd just need to do `new_dict['foo']['val_1']`  to achieve the same effect. 
This is a lot faster and cheaper to construct because you re-use what you already have instead of re-creating it from scratch.

Comment: @RafaelC I've learned not to let it get to me, because it tends to happen.